# Fixed header moves down in IPhone wrapper while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I have created an Iphone wrapper for my single page web application like below 
[image]

When we reach at the top after scrolling down the container the header moves down and a white space on the top. I can  reproduce this issue in IPhone wrapper only. In browser the header will fixed correctly. is there any specific reason for this issue or is this is the default behavior of IPhone? if not how can i resolve this?

Css i have applied to the header is

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
```

Comment: How did you fixed this issue????

Comment: i think this is a known issue in IPhone wrapper.Could you please test it in latest iphone latest version?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in micromax canvas 2

Answer (score -2):

did you try media query or important the css?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px){}
```